# General formula for convolution of discrete and continuous distribution

Tags: probability

Is there a general formula for the distribution function of $X+Y$ where X is a discrete random variable, and Y is continuous, with independence holding?

Comment: A formula for $X+Y$? I just wrote it down. Or are you thinking of its CDF?

Comment: @drhab yes, sorry, thats what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a countable set with $P(X\in A)=1$ and $p_a:=P(X=a)$ for $a\in A$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent then:

$$F_{X+Y}(z)=\sum_{a\in A}P(X+Y\leq z\mid X=a)P(X=a)=\sum_{a\in A}F_Y(z-a)p_a$$

This is as far as you can get in the general case.

In many cases we have $A=\mathbb N$ or $A=\mathbb Z$, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general formula for the convolution of two arbitrary probability measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$:

$$(\mu_1 * \mu_2)(A) = \int \mu_1(A - x) \; d\mu_2(x) = \int \mu_2(A - x) \; d\mu_1(x)$$

If you want to calculate the CDF of the convolution, you need to set $A = (-\infty, t]$:
$$(\mu_1 * \mu_2)((-\infty, t]) = \int P_1(t-x) \; d\mu_2(x) = \int P_2(t-x) \; d\mu_1(x)$$

Whether one of these formulae is really applicable depends on the distributions themself.